How to reduce validator activation time (on a testnet)?
I have a testnet that is running quite well
Even withdrawals are activated (it is running on Ethereum Capella update)
Now, the issue is, a new validator takes nearly 8 hours to be activated (e.g if i submit a deposit for the validator at 2 pm, it will start producing blocks/attesting at 10 pm on the same day)
I know i can change a few parameters in the config.yaml file of the consensus client and make the blockchain produce blocks faster
But, the network that i have currently running, contains important data that our research group does not want to lose.
Therefore, i would like to know how to change the parameters of a network that is already up and running?
for reference, i have all the nodes under my control, so i can do anything that requires network consensus
Please advise on how i can reduce the validator activation time in the test network
P.S : we're using geth as execution client and lighthouse as consensus client
